# Add as link with VisualSVN

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I've got a solution in which I'm trying to create a 2nd executable. These two executable share most of the same files, but have a few different ones including resources and application icon, etc.

I created the 2nd project, and added the items as links.:

1. Right-click **"Add existing item"**,
2. Browse to it,
3. Click the **"Add"** drop-down and select **"Add as link"**.

*Adding as links means that it just references the other file in the other folder and does not copy it.*

Now, when I tried to commit my project VisualSVN / SVN tried to do an SVN add on those files in the logical path they belong to resulting in lots of errors that the file was not found. It caused the entire commit to fail and was a major pain in the ass.

Is there a good way I can add links to files without side-effects? All the files I'm trying to link to are already in the same repo.

**Update**

Maybe I should add more information about what I'm trying to accomplish because I'm open to any suggestion which helps me accomplish it.

I have a project structure something like this... Or I want it to be like this...

```
MyProject
  /Common
    BusinessDataObjects (svn:external)
    ControlsLibrary (svn:external)
    OtherCommmonLib1 (svn:external)
    OtherCommonLib2 (svn:external)
  /Modules
    Module1
    Module2
    Module3
    ...
   Application1
   Application2 (shares all App1's files, except different .resx, icon, name, other minor differences)
   SetupProject1 (includes app1 and certain module dlls)
   SetupProject2 (includes app2 and certain module dlls)
```

The application is basically an empty shell (using Prism) which loads the modules installed in a /modules folder. I want both applications to be almost identical, but I want them to have different names and a different icon. I thought I could accomplish this by adding the files from the first project to the second as a link, and simply swapping a resource file which included the strings for the application window title, About dialog, etc. But then VisualSVN or whatever tried to SVN Add those items which I wasn't expecting.

I need to be able to develop the modules and the application's shell project. They are not stable in any way yet. I just want them to near copies of each other but with minor naming differences. I figured with two application projects, I could have two setup projects that included the output from each application and whichever modules are supposed to be included in that version of the software program.

I was trying to make this as foolproof as possible, and I'd like to avoid having to update external references to the same project. (I'm a bit confused about that as well, would I svn:external to the **same** repo?) That doesn't sound good, but this was my main idea on how to create two almost identical apps. I'm not sure how else I'll do it if I can't get my version control software to behave.

I had suggested oringally we only have one version of the software and have certain modules be upgrades, but there are some good reasons they can't really do that.

Comment: Why do you use "add as link" when you have powerful source-control?

Comment: @bahrep Please see my update, I'm still not sure if svn:externals is what I would need

Answer (score 1):

When you add a file to a Visual Studio project with **"Add as link"** it's expected that the file is not copied to the project's folder.

VisualSVN considers status of items in your working copy, even files which are not included in the current solution. However a linked file does not exist in a working copy, thus can't be tracked. It's out of version-control.

Since the files you attempt to link are already version-controlled (i.e. they exist in the SVN repository) it makes sense to use [Externals Definitions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) (`svn:externals` property) to link them.

Also see [TortoiseSVN Manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-common-projects.html#tsvn-howto-common-externals); it's description of `svn:externals` is really good.

Comment: I'm not sure that svn:externals is what I want. We already use svn:externals to link other version controlled projects (from a different repo) into the same solution. This makes it easy for us to manage dependencies between different projects without paths being different on different development boxes. However, with svn:externals if I make a change to the linked project, I have to manually update the revision number, which I don't want to have to manage. If you leave it to "head" revision, then the files states won't match, if I check it a previous rev. I use svn:external when in a different.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention your environment. However, you mention you have a *Solution*. I'm assuming it's VisualStudio you're using.

Have you tried AnkhSVN which is a Source Control Provider for Subversion for VisualStudio? AnknSVN integrates into VisualStudio much like Microsoft's native version control systems of Visual SourceSafe and TeamFoundation. I believe you can use AnknSVN to do the *linking* you want since these links are really internal VisualStudio structures and not actual symbolic or hard links like you find in a Unix system.

I usually avoid links (I believe they're called Junctions on Windows) because they simply don't work across operating systems. Instead, you can use one of the following methods:

- Use your build system to copy the files, or create the required links rather than your version control system.
- Use `svn:externals` to do the linking. Careful with this because `svn:externals` are pointers to a Subversion URL.

For example, if I setup `http://foo.com/svn/trunk/proj1` to have a `svn:externals` link to the head of `http://foo.com/svn/trunk/proj2`, and I create a tag for Project 1 by copying `http://foo.com/svn/trunk/proj1` to `http://foo.com/svn/tags/REL-1.2/proj1`, that project is still pointing to the head of the trunk of proj2. Changes in Project 2 will change what I thought was a stable tag. Always point your `svn:external` to a stable revision.

Comment: I'm not sure svn:externals is what I want. I want two executables, but I want them to have different names, titles, and application icon. And it is very important to make sure the names never get crossed. I'm trying to set it up to share the main shell window, but have a different .resx file for title names, and also point to a different application icon etc. Any small changes I need to make would be separate. With svn:externals, wouldn't I constantly have to manage the linked revision number? And changing it, would require a commit which changes the rev. Sounds tricky.

Comment: I thought adding files as links would **only** affect the .csproj file. Also, we already have purchased two licenses and have been using VisualSVN. Switching to AnkhSVN, wouldn't be that desirable... Maybe there's a better way to make two applications share their files but have different window titles, and icons, names. I also planned on creating two setup projects, one for each application, which included different modules. Usually a setup project targets the output of another project.

Answer (score -2):

I have no experience with VisualSVN, we use Ankhsvn which does not have that problem.

http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/